# Send Key to App Engine Endpoint

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Im trying to send an object to Google App Engine Endpoints which contains a key. But the object cannot be deserialized. This is the error I'm getting:

```
java.io.IOException:     com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: 
(was java.lang.NullPointerException) 
(through reference chain:
Form["identity"]->FormsIdentity["user"]->User["key"]->com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key["appId"])
```

And this is the object Im sending:

```
    "identity":{
    "user":
    {
       "key" : {
              "kind" : "User",
              "appId" : "no_app_id",
              "id" : "1",
              "complete" : true,
              "namespace" : ""
            },
      "googleID" : "8493582",
      "emailAddress" : "xxxxx@gmail.com",
      "credential" : "xxxx@gmail.com"
    },
    "deviceID":"4234o34i523534"
}
```

But Im only getting the error for the frontend, because the code inside the endpoint is  executed.

Answer (score 0):

When the key is serialized to json, it will try to call getAppId() from Key.class

```
  public String getAppId() {
    return appIdNamespace.getAppId();
  }
```

As you can see this getter tries to access appIdnamespace, which in your case is likely null. The appIdnamespace cannot not be explicitly set, but it is generated when you create the key with a KeyFactory, or after the datastore has persisted the object.

Since you didn't post the code for the method returning this identity object, I don't know for sure why your user keys don't have a appIdnamespace set, but my guess is that you are not returning an object that has been persisted or that the key has not been created properly.